# .xcconfig? How to set environment variables

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm new to Xcode.

I spent the last two days trying to figure out how to test my app on my iPhone which accesses a web service. On the simulator I can use a hard-coded 'localhost' variable, but I don't want to hardcode all the configuration settings.

I'm using Swift + Xcode 6 but I think this is the same process as Xcode 5.

I looked through lots of articles and I think I'm supposed to use .xcconfig, but it's very unclear.

For example, I created a `Environment.xcconfig` file. I populated it with

```
API_BASE_URL = "http://localhost:4000/api/v1"
```

I then went into Project -> Info and set the Debug configuration file to `Environment`.

I then tried to access the variable in code via `${API_BASE_URL}` but I get `Use of unresolved identifier 'API_BASE_URL'`.

This is extremely frustrating. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

1. Setup config hierarchy in case you have pods configs:
   [image]

OR if you haven't any pods at all, the Configurations hierarchy gonna look like this:
[image]

2. Create all the key-value pairs for each config file (in this case there are 3 config files for dev/adhoc/appstore builds). Each config file has same set of keys:
   [image]
3. Add each key to the generator:
   [image]
4. Then just use the keys in your code :
   [image]

**PS: the keys generated this way are also recognizable in .swift files (make sure you have a bridging header in your Swift project, even though you don't use obj-c sources and it will be empty).**

**UPDATE for Swift 2.2: doesn't work anymore** [Swift 2.2: GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS constants no longer imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36266789/swift-2-2-gcc-preprocessor-definitions-constants-no-longer-imported)

Comment: It seems I am not able to read these values from Swift. Am I being delusional?

Comment: @exalted did you include generator file? Anyway, try to generate definitions in same xcconfig file

Comment: the key thing is to define `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = FOO=‘$(FOO)’` correct?

Comment: @exalted yes. don't forget `$(inherited)`

Comment: oh boy, that works! Could you please explain the “magic” behind `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS`? Why is it “special” than any other key that its values are available in code?

Comment: @exalted well, GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS tells the compiler preprocessor to grab all the following keys and keep them in mind while preprocessing our code. Not sure if it is absolutely right point though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90744/discussion-between-exalted-and-purrrminator).

Comment: @purrrminator can you tell, how do you access these values from Swift? From what I see in Apple docs: `preprocessor directives are not imported in Swift`

Comment: @EvgenyAleksandrov just follow the steps I described in the answer

Comment: @purrrminator I did this many times in obj-c projects, so I know all these steps. But I see this in Swift: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tgzzbs312lw0381/Screenshot%202016-02-25%2012.02.40.png?dl=0

Comment: Found issue. Bridging header is needed (empty is enough) for preprocessor directives to work in Swift.

Comment: @EvgenyAleksandrov oh. ok

Comment: @purrrminator after updating to Xcode 7.3 again I can't access these values from Swift (in the same project that was working fine before). Do you have same issue?

Comment: @EvgenyAleksandrov Yes, this is a known bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36266789/swift-2-2-gcc-preprocessor-definitions-constants-no-longer-imported

Answer (score 1):

You don't want `.xcconfig`; that stores settings for Xcode. Instead, you want a property list (`.plist`) file. To do so, hit `command-N` to create a new file, then select `iOS > Resources > Property List`. Use the plist editor to add keys, values, and value types. Then load your properties by adding these lines somewhere in your app:

```
if let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Latin Conjugations", ofType:"plist") {
    let plist = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile:filePath)
}
```

You can then access your properties via the plist dictionary like you would any other dictionary value. Note that it's not a Swift `Dictionary`, since that doesn't have a constructor that takes a file path to load.

**Updated 10/21/2015:** This answer is now Swift 2.0-compliant. `pathForResource()` now returns an Optional.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. If I have 3 environments: Development, Staging, Production, should I create 3 plist files? If so, how do I tell Xcode which plist to load for simulator, device, production?

Comment: @NRitH the result for `pathForResource` is an optional though, so I would conditional unwrap it.

Comment: @PaulPeelen, when I answered this more than a year ago, `pathForResource()` did not return an optional. I'll update my original answer.

Comment: Yes, I do want xcconfig. The difference: values from xcconfig will be put into your code, whereas plist will remain as plain-text. So imagine an API-Key - we should try to protect it as much as possible, and placing it inside our code is the best thing. Using xcconfig allows us to easily replace values in CLI/CI -> continous integration

Comment: xcconfig are Xcode config settings. Their purpose is to store settings for Xcode. Recommended viewing is “Explore advanced project configuration in Xcode”, WWDC21-10210. See https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10210/

Recommend editing this answer as I think what @NRitH actually means is “don’t use xcconfig to store environmental variables”.