# Swift 2.2: GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS constants no longer imported

Tags: xcode, swift

The [technique to separate API keys in a xcconfig file described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32540064/569448) doesn't work with Swift 2.2 [due to a bug (SR-909)](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-909).

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for pointing to the bug, would not have figured this one out in a while. If it's any help I ended up adding an additional objc constants bridge to Swift and using the bridge constants from swift:

```
// Constants.h
extern NSString *const kDropBoxAPIKey;

// Constants.m
NSString *const kDropBoxAPIKey = DROPBOX_API_KEY;

// xxx-Bridging-Header.h
#import "Constants.h"
```

Then use the bridged key in Swift

```
// xx.swift
...
// let auth = DropboxAuth(appKey: DROPBOX_API_KEY) 
let auth = DropboxAuth(appKey: kDropBoxAPIKey)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare another similar macro in bridging header file. Imagine we have `MY_MACRO` macro in preprocessing definitions. Swift code does not see it. In bridging header file we can define another macro:

```
#define MY_MACRO2 MY_MACRO
```

Now use `MY_MACRO2` everywhere in Swift code. When Apple fixes this issue, you need rename `MY_MACRO2` to `MY_MACRO`.