# Getting xcconfig configuration file name from code

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, xcconfig

Is there a way in code to get the name of the .xcconfig file being used?

As in the picture below I would like to be able to find out the configuration is "Lab2"

[image]

Comment: I ended up going with the following solution : http://stackoverflow.com/a/32540064/4577878

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to read it...

Edit your Lab2.xcconfig file and add this

```
OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS = -DLAB2
```

and then inside your code

```
    #if LAB2
        print("Build using lab2.xcconfig")
    #else
        print("Build using some_other.xcconfig")
    #endif
```